# Tokenizing text content of an XML element using Dom Java

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML file that contains tags such as:

```
<P>(b) <E T="03">Filing of financial reports.</E> (1)(i) Except as provided in paragraphs (b)(3) and (h) of this section,</p>
```

I need to parse the text content and get the results back as an array of strings `["(b)", "Filing of financial reports.", "(1)(i) Except as provided in paragraphs (b) (3) and (h) of this section,"]`.

In other words, I need to tokenize the text content of a `<p>` element according to `<E T=03">` and store the results in an array of strings.

Comment: Ok, you could just use DOM parser with XPATH for this. DOM has a nodelist.  Loop the content from xml file and add to a NodeList Take the content from nodelist and add to a String[]

Comment: Do you mean `<p>(b) ...`? `<P(b) ...` is not valid XML.

Comment: It is a valid XML but the content got mixed up. I was not display the correct tags on the page.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to "tokenize", as the parsing has already been done for you when the DOM was built.  The `<P>` node contains both text *and* child nodes.  This is what the DOM looks like:

```
P
|
+---text "(b) "
|
+---E
|   |
|   +---attribute T=03
|   |
|   +---text "Filing of financial reports."
|
+---text "Except as provided ..."
```

To get the results you want you need to navigate through the sub-nodes of `<P>` and extract all the text nodes.

Comment: When I call the p.getTextContent(), I got the whole string back (string content of P and all child elements are mixed up) not what I see in your tree. Is there any way to get the strings in a way similar to your tree?

Comment: If you are getting unparsed nodes mixed in with your text then you are not using an XML parser.  You must post the code showing how you built the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

here's one way to do it using [jsoup library](http://jsoup.org/):

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;

class Test {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String xml = "<P>(b) <E T=\"03\">Filing of financial reports.</E> (1)(i) Except as provided in paragraphs (b)(3) and (h) of this section,</p>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml);
    for (Element e : doc.select("p"))
      for (Node child : e.childNodes()) {
        if (child instanceof TextNode) {
          System.out.println(((TextNode) child).text());
        } else {
          System.out.println(((Element) child).text());
        }
      }
  }
}
```

output:

```
(b) 
Filing of financial reports.
 (1)(i) Except as provided in paragraphs (b)(3) and (h) of this section,
```

Comment: This is very useful. But most of my code uses Dom and I am finding it very hard to pass the <p> tag elements to this application. When passing, the Dom library ignores all the tags and passes its text content only making it impossible to process. Is there any way to do the same in Dom?

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath. If you don't want to use specialized Java libraries, you may just use standard Java API such us:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class ExtractingAllTextNodes {

    private static final String XML = "<P>(b) <E T=\"03\">Filing of financial reports.</E> (1)(i) Except as provided in paragraphs (b)(3) and (h) of this section,</P>";

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        final DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        final DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        final String expression = "//text()";

        final Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(XML.getBytes()));

        final NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println("=> " + nodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
=> (b) 
=> Filing of financial reports.
=>  (1)(i) Except as provided in paragraphs (b)(3) and (h) of this section,
```

Depending on your needs, you may alter the XPath expression.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I finally managed to find a solution to the problem. The code is somewhat complex but it uses Dom which is the standard library for XML parsing:

```
public static void parseSection(Element sec){
    NodeList pTags = ((Element) (((NodeList) sec
            .getElementsByTagName("contents")).item(0)))
            .getElementsByTagName("P");
    int pTagIndex = 0;
    while (pTagIndex < pTags.getLength()) {
        System.out.println(pTagIndex);
        Node pTag = pTags.item(pTagIndex);
        NodeList pTagChildren = pTag.getChildNodes();
        int pTagChildrenIndex = 0;
        while(pTagChildrenIndex < pTagChildren.getLength()){
            Node pTagChild = pTagChildren.item(pTagChildrenIndex);
            if(pTagChild.getNodeName().equals("#text")){
                System.out.println("Text: " + pTagChild.getNodeValue());
            } else if(pTagChild.getNodeName().equals("E")){
                System.out.println("E: " + pTagChild.getTextContent());
            }
            pTagChildrenIndex ++;
        }
```